# How to hide and show views based on button clicks?

Tags: android, android-view

I have an `Activity` which uses the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start capture" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play video" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />    

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I hide `surfaceView` and show `videoView` when `btnPlay` is clicked?  I would also like to do something similar where `videoView` is hidden and `surfaceView` is shown when clicking `btnCapture`.

This is how I'm hiding and showing views:

```
surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: You will need to show us a little more of your code to see what else you are doing. That is how you would show a `View` and `Gone` wouldn't just hide it but remove it completely to make room for something else

Comment: I'd probably remove both the `SurfaceView` and `VideoView` from the layout file and put in a `FrameLayout` instead then create the `SurfaceView` or `VideoView` in code when needed and put them in the `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put both surfaceView and videoView in different Linearlayout and then play with linearlayout setVisibility() behind the btnCapture click.

maybe like this:

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) { 
if (surfaceView_linearlayout.getVisibility() == 0) {
    videoView_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    surfaceView_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} 

}
});

btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) { 
if (videoView_linearlayout.getVisibility() == 0) {
    surfaceView_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoView_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
});
```